# How to solve system of equations with modulo function?

Tags: linear-algebra, discrete-mathematics

If I have a system of equations like
\begin{align}
X &= g^{(a+2)(b+2)} \bmod p, \\
Y &= g^{(a+3)(b+3)} \bmod p, \\
Z &= g^{(a+4)(b+4)} \bmod p;
\end{align}
where $p$ (a prime number), $g$ and $X$ are known and $g$ and $p$ are co-prime.
Can we find $Y$ and $Z$ in terms of $X$?

So far, I have reached here:
\begin{align}
X &= g^{(ab+2a+2b+4)} \bmod p \\
&= [g^{ab} \bmod p \cdot g^{2(a+b)} \bmod p \cdot g^4 \bmod p] \bmod p; \\ 
Y &= g^{(ab+3a+3b+9)} \bmod p \\
&= [g^{ab} \bmod p \cdot g^{3(a+b)} \bmod p \cdot g^9 \bmod p] \bmod p; \\
Z &= g^{(ab+4a+4b+16)} \bmod p \\
&= [g^{ab} \bmod p \cdot g^{4(a+b)} \bmod p \cdot g^{16} \bmod p] \bmod p. 
\end{align}

Edit: as suggested if I simplify the exponents: $u=a+2$ and $v=b+2$, I get:
\begin{align}
X &= g^{uv} \bmod p, \quad\text{and} \\
Y &= g^{(u+1)(v+1)} \bmod p.
\end{align}

Still, I cannot express $Y$ in terms of $X$.

Comment: $u^{v+w}\ne u^v+u^w.$

Comment: Well, $g^{(a+3)(b+3)}= g^{(a+2)(b+3)+(b+3)}=q^{(a+2)(b+2) + (a+2)+(b+3)}=q^{(a+2)(b+2)}q^{a+b + 5}\equiv Xq^{a+b+5} \pmod p$ but I'm not sure we can get anything more useful unless we know somethings about $a,b$ or $p$.

Comment: @Anne Bauval Thank you. I have updated my question. Please let me know if my approach is still wrong.

Comment: @fleablood p is a prime number. a and b are like the exponents we would choose in a Diffie Hellman problem. g and p are known. a and b are not known.

Comment: You can assume $X,g\not\equiv0\bmod p.$ And simplify your notations by a change of unknowns: let $u=a+2,v=b+2.$ And wipe off $Z$ from your problem, since $ZX\equiv Y^2g^2\bmod p.$

Comment: Are the known integers $X,g$ supposed *a priori* to be such that mod $p$, $X$ *is* a power of $g$?

Comment: @Anne Bauval  If I make the changes you suggested I would have,
X = $g^{uv}$ mod p and Y = $g^{(u+1)(v+1)}$ mod p. Still I am not able to represent Y in terms of X. Am I missing something here?

Comment: I agree, that is the remaining (simpler) problem.

Comment: And what about my question about your hypothesis (or absence of) on $X,g$?

Comment: I did not make any such assumptions. This question is based on the classic Diffie Hellman key exchange.

Comment: Ok, so you don't assume that $g$ is a generator of $(\mathbb Z_p^*,\times)$. Other question: I don't understand why you ask for $Y$ "in terms of $X$" and not "in terms of $X,g,p$" (all of them being "known"). Note also that since $Y=g^{u+v}Xg$, asking for $Y$ is equivalent to asking for $g^{u+v}.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is equivalent (with the help of the comments above) to: given integers $p$ (prime) and $X,g$ (not dividible by $p$), find all $g^{u+v}$'s $\bmod p$ such that $X\equiv g^{uv}\bmod p$. Then, exhaustive search modulo the multiplicative order of $g\bmod p$ (of $w$, if any, such that $g^w\equiv X\bmod p$, and then of $u,v$ such that $w=uv$) seems the only way.

Comment: If we know, $g^{a +2}$ mod p and $g^{b +2}$ mod p. Can we find the $g^{u+v}$ required to solve this problem? If we can, could you tell me how?

Comment: Since we do not know a and b, we cannot find them given $g^{a+2}$ mod p or $g^{b+2}$ mod p [even if they are small numbers]. Is that correct?

Comment: 1) $g^{u+v}=g^ug^v=g^{a+2}g^{b+2}.$ 2) Given $g^c,$ we can find $c$ (modulo the multiplicative order of $g\bmod p$) by *exhaustive search*, as I said.